# Convert multiline text into List every Xth line in WPF

Tags: c#

I basically want to take the following example text and put it into a list.

The multiline text looks like this

```
12182718271827
Example
More Text
WEUIWEU
12718271892781
Example 2
More Text
WUQIWUQ
...
```

My list class looks like this:

```
public class Data {

public string id { get; set; }
public string employee { get; set; }
public string position { get; set; }
public string access { get; set; }

}
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Of course it can be achieved. What have you done/tried to achieve it? Show your work and we can help if you get stuck.

Comment: Andy, my question is up there, I asked how it can be achieved, if I had work to show, I would have shown it. It is ok though, the code below helped me figure out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Code not tested.

```
//Line position counter
int idCount = 0;
int employeeCount = 1;
int positionCount = 2;
int accessCount = 3;

//Create collection for data
ObservableCollection<Data> empData = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

//Read lines from text file and add them to an array
//Make sure the text file does not contain an empty lines
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TestFolder\Data.txt");

//Loops through the array and add every set of 4 items to collection
while(accessCount <= lines.Count())
{
empData.Add(new Data { id = lines[idCount], employee = lines[employeeCount], position = lines[positionCount], access = lines[accessCount]});

idCount += 4;
employeeCount += 4;
positionCount += 4;
accessCount += 4;
}
```

Comment: code-only answers teaches nothing to nobody. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.